# pandas find the previous instance index number of a matching value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the index number of a value in pandas. For example, in below table, I want to bring index numbers to column "Found"

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ["hit/miss", "Value", "Found?"]
data = {'hit/miss':['0', '0', '1', '0', '0','1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        'Value':["Not found","Not found","Yes!","Not found","Not found","Yes!","Not found","Not found","Not found","Not found"],
        'Found':["","","","2","2","2","5","5","5","5"]}

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Anyone have idea how I can iterate from bottom to top and find the matching value and get its index number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
found = df['hit/miss'].eq('1')
df['Found'] = found.mask(found, found.index.to_list()).shift().replace(False, None)
```